# Is it possible to invert a nested rust error type?

Tags: rust

How can I invert a Rust Error?

Let us say I have this type:

```
let a1: Result<Result<(), OuterError>, InnerError> = func();
```

How can I transform it into:

```
let a2: Result<Result<(), InnerError>, OuterError>> = ...
```

Comment: Appreciate this might seem a bit odd but it has implications for flow control.

Comment: Why is `func()` returning such a strange type in the first place? You can define your own error type (or grab some library to do it for you, like `thiserror` or `anyhow`), and then return a single-level `Result` from `func` that either contains an `OuterError` or `InnerError`.

Comment: It would be nice if func returned a nicer type.  But... it does not.

Comment: And it's impossible for you to change it?

Comment: Yes.   Otherwise I wouldn't have asked this question.   I know I can do it with an ugly match statement.  But I'd rather not.

Comment: The issue is that the InnerError is recoverable, while the outer error isn't.

Comment: Can't you handle `InnerError` first? There can only be either an inner or an outer error, so you don't have to duplicate control flow either way.

Answer (score 3):

AFAICT, Rust's standard library has no such method on `Result`. You can write your own trait implementing such a method on `Result<Result<T, EInner>, EOuter>` though:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct InnerError;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct OuterError;

trait InvertResult {
    type Output;

    fn invert(self) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<T, EOuter, EInner> InvertResult for Result<Result<T, EInner>, EOuter> {
    type Output = Result<Result<T, EOuter>, EInner>;

    fn invert(self) -> Self::Output {
        match self {
            Ok(Ok(v)) => Ok(Ok(v)),
            Ok(Err(e)) => Err(e),
            Err(e) => Ok(Err(e)),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo: Result<Result<u8, InnerError>, OuterError> = Ok(Err(InnerError));

    assert_eq!(foo.invert(), Err(InnerError));
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8b30f80312fc79dab7c8508a68f092ea)

Comment: It was proposed multiple times, but it was decided that when you need it you probably have a badly designed API. The `Ok` and `Err` variant make no sense when they're swapped.